# Agregar Certificado SSL de un dominio a subdominio

Tags: apache, ssl

Tengo un dominio principal (dominio.cl) en el que instalé la herramienta Letsencrypt para generar un certificado SSL para ese dominio . Posteriormente agregué un subdominio (sub.dominio.cl) y al momento de abrirlo en el navegador, me dice que el sitio no es seguro. Mi pregunta es, cómo seguro ese subdominio, teniendo un certificado ya instalado en el dominio principal?

Answer (score 2):

Pues como son sitios diferentes tiene sentido que cada sitio tenga su propio certificado, por lo que no podrías compartirlo.

Dado que son gratis, solo tienes que **solicitar uno para cada uno de tus dominios y subdominios**.

O esperar a enero del 2018 que es cuando Let's Encrypt empezará a [emitir certificados con comodín](https://letsencrypt.org/2017/07/06/wildcard-certificates-coming-jan-2018.html).

Answer (score 0):

Cada dominio posee lo que se llama un FQDN o nombre común, por ejemplo, no es lo mismo https://dominio.cl que http://subdominio.dominio.cl, para el SSL simple, un subdominio lo va a tratar igual que un dominio principal.

Entonces, si aseguras es nombre dominio.cl, no podrás, con ese mismo certificado simple asegurar subdominio.midominio.cl, por lo cual tienes una de dos

1. Emites otro certificado simple para el subdominio.

o

2. Emites un certificado WildCard, con el cual puedes asegurar el dominio principal (dominio.cl) y todos los demas sub dominios (*.dominio.cl).

Espero que la explicación te sirva.

Suerte!